# Why on Android, OpenCV camera is faster than the Android Camera when capturing video

Tags: android, opencv, android-camera, video-capture

In a project on Android, I'm trying to capture the video and process it in realtime (like a Kinect). I tried with two method: using OpenCV keep calling mCamera.grab() and capture.retrieve(mRgba,Highgui.CV_CAP_ANDROID_COLOR_FRAME_RGBA); or the Android's Camera by keep capturing image.

I feel that the OpenCV camera's ability to capture image faster than the Android one. But why?

Comment: If you are using "capture", i.e. takePicture(), you will definitely get slow response. Working with video in real time should be done through [setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer(android.hardware.Camera.PreviewCallback)) with `onPreviewFrame()` callback.

Comment: Strange, I had opposite experience, the opencv camera is obviously slower than the android one. +1 to @Alex, probably songyy did not use callback with buffer.

Comment: You should be using native camera view though, it is very fast.

Answer (score 5):

OpenCV uses a hack to get low level access to the Android camera. It allows to avoid several data copyings and transitions between native and managed layers.

Comment: Hi Andrey, that sounds very interesting, can you explain more details about what was done?